# Centering two divs in a footer

Tags: html, css, alignment, footer

Hi there I would need your help in vertical centering of those two elements in this footer, I would like them to be on same vertical level within footer. This is how it looks now:
[footer example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh6GB.png)

This is my code:

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 5%; left: 0; right:0; bottom: 0;
       background-color:#0065A0; color: #FFFFFF;">
  <footer>
    <div style="float:left; margin-left: 5%;">© 2014-2017 Calgarry</div>
    <div style="float:right; margin: 0 auto; margin-right: 5%;">Report</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Updated: I have done what VPx suggest, my code now look like this:

```
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 5%; left: 0; right: 0;  bottom: 0;
   background-color:#0065A0; color: #FFFFFF;">
     <footer style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; height: 100%;">   
        <div style="margin-left: 5%;">© 2014-2017 Calgarry</div>  
        <div style="margin-right: 5%;">Report</div>  
     </footer>
  </div>
```

It's hovewer still not working as it should, it now looks like this:

[second example of footer after suggested changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh6GB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `padding` for inner elements of footer. Remove`height` in footer.

```html
      <div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 0; right:0; bottom: 0;
       background-color:#0065A0; color: #FFFFFF;">
         <footer>   
          <div style="float:left; margin-left: 5%; padding: 20px">© 2014-2017 Calgarry</div>  
          <div style="float:right; margin: 0 auto; margin-right: 5%; padding: 20px">Report</div>  
         </footer>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your advice helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it with the **Flexbox**:

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* max. horizontal space between them */
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment / centering */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 20%; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: #0065A0; color: #FFFFFF;">
  <footer>   
    <div style="margin-left: 5%;">© 2014-2017 Calgarry</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 5%;">Report</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

For better presentation I increased the `height` of the outer div to `20%`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="position: fixed;width:100%;left:0;right:0;background-color:#0065A0; color: #FFFFFF;top:0;">
  <footer style="height: 50px;display:table;width:100%">
    <div style="text-align:left;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;    padding: 2%;">© 2014-2017 Calgarry</div>
    <div style="text-align:right; display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;    padding: 2%;">Report</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<div>© 2014-2017 Calgarry</div>
</div>
<div class = "col-sm-3">
<div>Report</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Try this!

Comment: you are using bootstrap, i think you should at least explain it

Comment: Yeah.. but Questioner will understand my code.. so maybe its not necessary to explain that.

Comment: i don't think he will understand, as if he do he won't ask such a question ... and an answer is intended to be complete and clear for everyone

Comment: also why introducing a whole framework for such a simple CSS thing ? it's a very bad idea

Answer (score -2):

easiest way is to add a padding top to the footer.

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 5%; left: 0; right:0; bottom: 0;
       background-color:#0065A0; color: #FFFFFF;">
  <footer style="padding-top: 0.5%;" >
    <div style="float:left; margin-left: 5%;">© 2014-2017 Calgarry</div>
    <div style="float:right; margin: 0 auto; margin-right: 5%;">Report</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```